# Guru Meditation Error Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled

Tags: c++, c

[error project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrqNU.png)

Guru Meditation Error in project
Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
I have project using pulsesensor with ESP32, Data from ESP32 is saved in database.
I tried many times but could not
help me

```
#include <ssl_client.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial

/* Konfigurasi pada SSID dan Password Wifi */
const char* ssid     = "berdikari";         
const char* password = "alfian24";  

/* Konfigurasi koneksi ke server */
char server[] = "192.168.43.108";     // Ganti dengan IP Address komputer aplikasi 
int port = 81;

/*konfigurasi*/
int PulseSensorPurplePin = 34;        // Pulse Sensor PURPLE WIRE connected to ANALOG PIN 0
int LED21 = 21;   //  The on-board Arduion LED
int Signal;                // holds the incoming raw data. Signal value can range from 0-102
float pulse=0;

WiFiClient client;
void setup() {
    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);         // Baudrate/kec. komunikasi pengiriman data ke serial terminal
  delay(10);
  Serial.println('\n');
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);      
  USE_SERIAL.print("Terhubung ke ");
  USE_SERIAL.print(ssid);

//  WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, dns);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    USE_SERIAL.print('.');
  }

  USE_SERIAL.print('\n');
  USE_SERIAL.println("Identitas ESP-32");  
  USE_SERIAL.print("IP Address:\t");
  USE_SERIAL.println(WiFi.localIP());         // IP Address ESP-32  

  USE_SERIAL.print('\n');
  USE_SERIAL.println("Identitas Web Server");
  USE_SERIAL.println("IP Address:");
  USE_SERIAL.print(server);
  USE_SERIAL.print("\tport:\t");
  USE_SERIAL.print(port);
}
void loop() {
  
    Signal = analogRead(PulseSensorPurplePin);  // Read the PulseSensor’s value.
                 // Send the Signal value to Serial Plotter.
delay(1000);

    pulse = Signal;
    USE_SERIAL.println(pulse);

  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
    //URL target untuk menyimpan data sensor Pulse ke database
    String url = "http://192.168.43.108:81/";
    url += "sistem_monitoring/Monitoring/simpan/";
    url += String(pulse);

    HTTPClient http;
    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    http.begin(url);
    USE_SERIAL.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
    
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    if(httpCode > 0) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", 
        httpCode);
      
         if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
            String payload = http.getString();
            USE_SERIAL.println(payload);
         }
      } else {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", 
        http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      } 
      http.end();
   }
}
```

please help me.
What should I do??
I've seen this question asked a few times but never got a good answer.

Comment: Attach a debugger or otherwise figure out what instruction is at 0x4010fc00

Comment: I just tried this code and everything works fine. Is it the whole code or just a part? Because it may be a lack of RAM.